# Is Mantra diksha (initiation) possible online?

Tags: mantras, tantra, guru, initiation

Is it possible to have mantra Initiation online?
How to know hoax among real Guru? How to know that mantra you will be given is initiated?

Comment: I would request/give a humble advice not to take diksha online.Instead visit offline centers for guidance eg: Ramakrishna Mission Centers are established in many cities and towns and provide diksha. Similarly for Dvaita/Vishistadvaita/Agama-Tantra visit their maths/temples in your respective town/city for further guidance.

Comment: thanks. Outside India like European countries   if there is an option? or when in India where and who?